# 'two' Regular expression between two regular expressions

Tags: regex

I have a .asc file with around 80 000 lines and I want to extract some specific lines from the file.

I have tried to make it easier for me by putting to specific lines (one before and one after) the areas where I want to extract information/ lines (150 areas).

The 'start' regex `(MSG\s*(\d{1,8})\sSHOWING\sSENTENCE)` so I want to look for lines after this occur

the 'end' regex `(MSG\s*(\d{1,8})\sSENTENCE\sGONE)` so when this occur I won't have anything returned until the 'start' regex appear again.

There will be hundreds of lines between these two regex expressions, but I only want those matching these regex's

```
(EFIX\sR\s*(\d{1,8})\s*(\d{1,8})\s*(\d{1,3})\s*(\d{1,3}).\d\s*(\d{1,3}).\d\s*(\d{1,4}) or (ESACC\sR\s*(\d{1,8})\s*(\d{1,8})\s*(\d{1,3})\s*(\d{1,3}).\d\s*(\d{1,3}).\d\s*(\d{1,4}).
```

How would I go about this in Python?

Comment: Here's a similar Q&A in ruby: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17457440/ruby-line-by-line-match-range

Ruby supports the .. operator. In python you'll have to code it in a loop. But the same Q&A contains examples for that too.

Comment: In the pattern of `EFIX...`, is `.` the literal dot or a dot which matches any single character?

Comment: It is a literal dot yes (@ccf). I typicall looks like this: 
ESACC R  1075390 1075414 25   144.3   526.2    54.3   547.2    1.86     162

Answer (score 0):

It could be easily done with the following steps:

1. Capture contents in between 'start' regex and 'end' regex patterns;
2. match:

   `(EFIX\sR\s*(\d{1,8})\s*(\d{1,8})\s*(\d{1,3})\s*(\d{1,3})\.\d\s*(\d{1,3})\.\d\s*(\d{1,4}) or (ESACC\sR\s*(\d{1,8})\s*(\d{1,8})\s*(\d{1,3})\s*(\d{1,3})\.\d\s*(\d{1,3})\.\d\s*(\d{1,4})\.`

So the sample code could be:

```
import re

P1 = 'MSG\s*\d{1,8}\sSHOWING\sSENTENCE([\s\S]+?)MSG\s*\d{1,8}\sSENTENCE\sGONE'
P2 = 'EFIX\sR\s*\d{1,8}\s*\d{1,8}\s*\d{1,3}\s*\d{1,3}\.\d\s*\d{1,3}\.\d\s*\d{1,4}|ESACC\sR\s*\d{1,8}\s*\d{1,8}\s*\d{1,3}\s*\d{1,3}\.\d\s*\d{1,3}\.\d\s*\d{1,4}\.'
sample = """
ESACC R 000000 7777 333.3 222 1111.
MSG 2355688 SHOWING SENTENCE
some text in between
EFIX R 5656 7878 123 456.8 122.9 5656
some text 1 here
some text 2 here
ESACC R 1075390 1075414 25  144.3   526.2   54.3 547.2  1.86    162
some text 3 here
some text 4 here
EFIX R 1212 505050 222 000.2 129.9 1010
some text 1 here
some text 2 here
ESACC R 1212 505050 222 000.2 129.9 1010.
some text 3 here
some text 4 here
MSG 2355688 SENTENCE GONE
EFIX R 5555555 8888888 9 666.6 999.8 0000
"""
in_between = re.findall(P1, sample)
for txt in in_between:
    print re.findall(P2, txt)
```

Output:

```
['EFIX R 5656 7878 123 456.8 122.9 5656', 'ESACC R 1075390\t1075414\t25\t144.3\t526.2\t54.', 'EFIX R 1212 505050 222 000.2 129.9 1010', 'ESACC R 1212 505050 222 000.2 129.9 1010.']
```